# Transferring Muscat on two different Airlines

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, airport-transfer, oman, muscat

I will be traveling from Doha to Dubai via Muscat on 2 different airlines Qatar Airways & Swiss Airlines. I have a transit time of 1:50 at around 10:00pm. Since these are on separate tickets and separate flights would I have to go through immigration pick up my checked baggage. Then go through customs and leave the arrivals terminal and go drop it off at departures. Then go through security there? Is the transit time of 1 hour and 50 minutes sufficient for this?

Also since I'll technically be entering the country of Oman as an American citizen do I need a special Visa ahead of time? Thank you.

Comment: Unless there is a special service that would do this for you (this is quite rare but exists in Dubai airport), yes, you would need to deplane, clear immigration, reclaim your bags, go through customs, get to the check-in area and drop your bags **before the check-in deadline**, which is often 1 hour (haven’t checked your specific case). Seems very difficult to me in normal conditions, impossible if there are any delays. Remember that if you miss the check-in deadline, you’ll be considered a no-show, and will have to book and pay for a new ticket. They may even cancel subsequent segments.

Comment: I don't know what day you are flying, but I picked a random date in July and found that single bookings for DOH-DXB were significantly cheaper than the separate tickets proposed here (e.g. DOH-KWI-DXB on Jazeera, or DOH-MCT-DXB on Oman Air).

Comment: I would contact airlines. Sometime they can link baggage (also on different tickets), this will simplify your visa requirements, and transfer time. So check with both airlines (do no trust only one), and get an alternative flight (a flight after 24+2 hours is bad for not having a visa). Oman is also simplifying procedures for tourists, so attention on older [as few years] information you may find on web)

Answer (score 2):

Two hours is very unlikely to be enough time for this self-connection.

You would need to clear immigration to reclaim your bags, and then check them in with the next airline yourself.

You can be visa exempt if you arrive from Dubai or Qatar with a visa/entrance stamp from those countries. It's also possible to obtain a 21 day visa on arrival, but only if your connection time is more than six hours. Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in part:

> Visa required, except for Nationals of USA with a visa or an
>   entrance stamp for Qatar if arriving directly from Qatar (visa
>   must specify that it is valid for travel to Oman and must be
>   valid for at least one month on arrival) , or:
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
>   ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They
>   must stay in the international transit area of the airport and
>   have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of USA with a normal
>   passport traveling on business in transit for more than 6
>   hours can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 3
>   weeks.

As international check-in closes an hour before departure, you have 50 minutes to clear immigration, claim your bags, clear customs, and check-in your bags for your next flight. And that's if your arriving flight is on time. If you're an Olympic sprinter and immigration is quiet, you could pull it off. But remember Murphy's Law. Your flight may be late, immigration could be a madhouse, and you might be randomly selected for a customs check.

Comment: And today I learned that there are no direct flights between Doha and Dubai, and [why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017%E2%80%9319_Qatar_diplomatic_crisis).